Unable to decrypt JWE payload
I am trying to sign and encrypt my payload. When the other party tries to decrypt my data it returns

AES/GCM/NoPadding decryption failed: Tag mismatch!

error. Can anyone help me to figure out the problem?
I am using https://web-token.spomky-labs.com/ JWT framework 3.3 version
My Code:
public static function encryptPayload($payload)
    {
        $payload = json_encode($payload);
        $selfPrivateKey = self::getSelfPrivateKey();
        $publicKey = self::getPublicKey();

      //  -----   Build JWS Object    -----   Begin   -----
        // Init JWS algorithm
        $jwsAlgorithmManager = new AlgorithmManager([new RS256()]);
        // Build JWS object and sign the message by merchant's private key
        $jwsBuilder = new JWSBuilder($jwsAlgorithmManager);
        $jws = $jwsBuilder
            ->create()
            ->withPayload($payload)
            ->addSignature($selfPrivateKey, [
                'alg' => 'RS256',
                'kid' => 0002,
            ])
            ->build();
            $jwsSerializer = new JwsCompactSerializer();
            $jwsString = $jwsSerializer->serialize($jws, 0);
            //  -----   Build JWS Object    -----    END    -----
    
            //  -----   Build JWE Object    -----   Begin   -----
            // Init JWE algorithm
            $jweKeyEncryptionAlgorithmManager = new AlgorithmManager([
                new RSAOAEP256(),
            ]);
            // Init JWE encryption algorithm
            $jweContentEncryptionAlgorithmManager = new AlgorithmManager([
                new A128GCM(),
            ]);
            $compressionMethodManager = new CompressionMethodManager([
                new Deflate(),
            ]);
            // Build JWE object and encrypt the message by public key
            $jweBuilder = new JWEBuilder(
                $jweKeyEncryptionAlgorithmManager,
                $jweContentEncryptionAlgorithmManager,
                $compressionMethodManager
            );
            $jwe = $jweBuilder
                ->create()
                ->withPayload($jwsString)
                ->withSharedProtectedHeader([
                    'alg' => 'RSA-OAEP-256',
                    'enc' => 'A128GCM',
                    'kid' => '0005',
                ])
                ->addRecipient($publicKey)
                ->build();

            $jweSerializer = new JweCompactSerializer();
            $jweString = $jweSerializer->serialize($jwe, 0);
            //  -----   Build JWE Object    -----    END    -----
           // $this->logger->info("Encrypted String: $jweString");
            return $jweString;
    }


I can decrypt the encrypted token generated by the posted PHP code and verify the resulting nested signed token using standard JWE/JWS online tools. So the posted code seems to work. The problem is probably due to different logics on both sides or a bug in the implementation of the other side. Since you have not posted anything about the other side (apart from the error message), it is hard to identify the problem. Post the code of the other side.

Also check the consistency of the RSA keys.

Are you sure $publicKey  corresponds to the recipient public key?

Thanks @Topaco and Spomky-Labs. Apparently the issue was from the other party who didn't implement the decryption properly. Its fixed after I highlighted all the answers to them.
